c# razor app, multithreading issue with "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context" issue
This is a .NET Razor app. I have an AJAX call in the CSHTML to a onpost method. The OnPost does some DB stuff, then calls a method that I would like to run in its own thread. If I await the method things work, but I need it to go off and do its thing and let user continue on form.  It alwaus fails at the _context2.Attach(mo).State EntityState.Modified; with error Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context. I have tried task/thread, changing return type to IactionResult etc.. always same issue.  Sorry new to threading in C#. Any Ideas
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostSignup(MarketOperator MarketOperator, Boolean Confirm = false)
{
Does some DB stuff
_context.Attach(RAExists).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   //Task.Run(async () =>  AI_Creation(_context,MarketOperator.MarketDescription, 
   //MarketOperator.MOID));

   Thread t3 = new Thread(() => AI_Creation(_context, 
   MarketOperator.MarketDescription, MarketOperator.MOID));
   t3.Start();

}

public async Task<IActionResult> AI_Creation(AppDbContext context,string idea, int moid)
{
//calls a bunch of open-ai calls which are awaited..  These work
enter code here
AppDbContext _context2 = context;
MarketOperator mo = await _context2.MarketOperator.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ra => ra.MOID == moid);
mo.Keywords = aI_Answers.keywords;

 _context2.Attach(mo).State = EntityState.Modified;
 await _context2.SaveChangesAsync()

}


Have you tried a fire & forget approach _ = Task.Run(() =>?

Yep I tried both Task.Run(async () =>  and Task.Run( () =>

Do not share a (presumably EF Core) DB Context across threads, DB Context is explicity made to be short lived and for each unit of work to get it's own. You should also take a look at hosted services for your long running background task.

That's because EF context is registered as scoped service by default.
What you can do is however, is to create own scope - for that you need to inject IServiceProvider to your controller.
So you define
private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

and assign it in contructor.
Then first thing (before serviceProvider gets disposed) in method you need to create scope:
public async Task<IActionResult> AI_Creation(string idea, int moid)
{
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    // you can use resolve context later on like this
    using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();


Awesome, this did the trick. Thank you so much for your time and answer
